# How is this passage written in the original language & how should it be interpreted?

Tags: christology, 1-john

1 John 5:20

> And we know that the Son of God has come and has given us an understanding, that we may know Him who is true; and we are in Him who is true, in His Son Jesus Christ. This is the true God and eternal life.

Comment: Is there a particular part you want clarity on?

Comment: A similar question, and the various answers received, may help you: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/80129/who-is-the-true-god-and-eternal-life?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who is the True God and Eternal Life?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/80129/who-is-the-true-god-and-eternal-life)

Comment: See https://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_john/5-20.htm